# Accesing a class with properties from another class returns null values

Tags: vb.net

I am making an application that reads values from a meter that is connected to my computer via a serial cable. When i press a button i send a command to the meter and after a few miliseconds i get a response back from the meter with the answer.
I am saving these values to a class that has properties init, so that i can access these values from anywhere.

So my problem is that when i try to get the values back it returns a 'nothing value', and its probably from the initialization i have that has a '**New**' like this'**Dim clsSavedValues As New clsSavedValues**', so when i try to get the values from that property class i create a new instanse and that instanse is empty if am not mistaken.

Ill post the code below but here is how the code flows:
I have 3 classes. MainClass, ProtocolClass, PropertiesClass.
From main i call a method inside ProtocolClass, and that method sends a command to the meter. after a few miliseconds i get a call back inside ProtocolClass anf this method is called '**Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived**' and it saves that return value to the PropertiesClass.
And after the DataReceived method is finished i go back to the MainClass and call another method to get the values from the PropertiesClass that i just saved but they return null. I know they are saved correctly because i can access them if i call them from within the ProtocolClass. But they are null from MainClass.

Here is my code:
**MainClass**

```
'Here i call the ProtocolClass
 Private Sub btnGetLastTransaction_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetLastTransaction.Click
        clsProtocol.GetLastTransaction(1, Integer.Parse(tbxTransactionPosition.Text))
    End Sub

'Here i try to read the valies from PropertiesClass
    Public Sub RetrieveMeterSerialNumber()
        Dim clsSavedValues As New clsSavedValues
        lblMeterSerialNumber.Text = clsSavedValues.SaveMeterSerialNumber
    End Sub
```

**ProtocolClass**

```
 Public Sub GetLastTransaction(ByVal destinationAddress As String, ByVal transactionNum As Integer)
        clsSavedValues = New clsSavedValues 'Creating Instance of the properties class
        Try
            Dim v_bodyOfMessage As [Byte]() = {ASCIItoHEX("G"), _
                                               ASCIItoHEX("r")}
            Dim v_bytearray As [Byte]() = ConstructCommand(v_bodyOfMessage)

            SendCommand(v_bytearray)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Meter serial number button click exception: {0}", ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived
    If comOpen Then
        Try
            ReDim rx(rxPacketSize)
            Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE")
            For i = 0 To rxPacketSize - 1
                readByte = SerialPort.ReadByte.ToString
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString & ": " & Conversion.Int(readByte).ToString)
                rx(i) = Conversion.Int(readByte).ToString

                If i <> 0 Then
                    If Convert.ToByte(rx(i)) = vDelimeterFlag(0) Then Exit For
                End If
            Next
            DecodeResponse()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("SerialPort_DataReceived Exception: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GetMeterSerialNumber()
    Dim i_startPosition As Integer = 5
    Dim meterSerialNumber As String = GetRemainingPortionOfString(i_startPosition)
    clsSavedValues.SaveMeterSerialNumber = meterSerialNumber
    frmExplorer.RetrieveMeterSerialNumber() 'This is the call to the main class
End Sub
```

**PropertiesClass**

```
Public Property SaveMeterSerialNumber() As String
    Get
        Return _MeterSerialNumber
    End Get
    Set(ByVal meterSerialNumber As String)
        _MeterSerialNumber = meterSerialNumber
    End Set
End Property
```

I want to get the values from the PropertiesClass because ill get more than wan response from the meter and that causes thread issues and i cannot keep track with them. So i save the values in one class and then i want to access them all from that class.
Sorry for the long post, ask me anything you want for clarification

Comment: If you want to store only one value for the application domain (the exe) you need to use static properties. In this case is not necessary to make the "New", simply refer the class property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clsSavedValues in SerialPort_DataReceived() and in your Main Class RetrieveMeterSerialNumber() are two different objects (with same variable names but each 'new' create a new instance of clsSavedValues ) maybe you should pass the clsSavedValues var from protocol to Main as parameter.

Main :

```
  Public Sub RetrieveMeterSerialNumber(clsSavedValues As clsSavedValues )
        lblMeterSerialNumber.Text = clsSavedValues.SaveMeterSerialNumber
    End Sub
```

Protocol :

```
Private Sub GetMeterSerialNumber()
    Dim i_startPosition As Integer = 5
    Dim meterSerialNumber As String = GetRemainingPortionOfString(i_startPosition)
    clsSavedValues.SaveMeterSerialNumber = meterSerialNumber
    frmExplorer.RetrieveMeterSerialNumber(clsSavedValues) 'This is the call to the main class
End Sub
```

or use a static property in your PropertiesClass

Comment: it was rather simple. I didnt think of that thanks Emmanuel:)